# Recurring payments - how long is a month?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

For monthly recurring payments, how long is a month defined to be? I need to be able to independently track subscription end dates on my web service and I'd like to be consistent with PayPal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on PayPal's documentation:

> How Subscriptions with Monthly Billing Cycles Work
>
> For monthly billing cycles, recurring payments are collected on the
>   same day of the month. If the initial recurring payment falls on the
>   31st, PayPal eventually adjusts the billing cycle to the 1st of the
>   month. If the initial recurring payment falls on the 29th or 30th,
>   PayPal adjusts the billing cycle to the 1st of the month on the
>   following February.
>
> When Monthly Recurring Payments Are Due and Collected on the 31st
>
> The subscription terms are:
>
> $25.99 USD a month; the subscriber signs up on Thursday, July 31. The
>   subscriber is billed as follows:
>
> Thursday, July 31 = $25.99 USD Saturday, August 31 = $25.99 USD
>   Wednesday, October 1= $25.99 USD Saturday, November 1= $25.99 USD and
>   so on... Notice that no recurring monthly payment was collected in
>   September, but recurring payments were collected roughly every 30
>   days.
>
> When Monthly Recurring Payments Are Due and Collected on the 30th
>
> The subscription terms are:
>
> $25.99 USD a month; the subscriber signs up on Tuesday, December 30.
>   The subscriber is billed as follows:
>
> Tuesday, December 30 = $25.99 USD Friday, January 30 = $25.99 USD
>   Sunday, March 1= $25.99 USD Wednesday, April 1= $25.99USD and so on...
>   Notice that no recurring monthly payment was collected in February,
>   but recurring payments were collected roughly every 30 days.

Read more at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142832/confusion-with-paypals-monthly-billing-cycle seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Am going through the same issues. It seems I should avoid using the 29th - 31st as recurring payment due date due to the inconsistences of our calendar. Does this mean then The new users who signup to my monthly subscription on say 29th get the first three days free, as I'll re-adjust the payment date to the first? Is that what you did?