# Confusion with PayPal's monthly billing cycle

Tags: paypal

I have implemented PayPal Payments Standard regarding processing subscriptions in our website. We have subscription plans for monthly/yearly.

As per the link [https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADF60L0E6](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-%20%20standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/#id08ADF60L0E6) PayPal says if a monthly billing cycle starts at 30th of January, the next billing cycle will be adjusted to 1st of March. But in live, it is different. I found that PayPal is billing on 28th of February. Is there any updated link of PayPal regarding this billing change? This is because, we need to display an expiration date to our customer for the current billing cycle/subscription.

Now I have doubts about the following:

1. How PayPal will adjust if the monthly billing cycle starts at 31st of January? Feb 28th or March 1st or March 2nd.
2. How PayPal will adjust if the yearly billing cycle starts at 29th February of a leap year? February 28th or March 1st.

My concern about billing date is that we are displaying the expiration dates to customers of current subscription. With no clear information of next billing date from PayPal, I am confused which date to display for next billing cycle.

Please let me know if any one is already handling these issues.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I am having the same problem now. I even found that there is 7 hours time difference in agreement `start_date` from the one which was send in `JSON` request. Have you found out the solution for this?

Comment: @viper are you specifying the right timezone on `start_date`? Regarding the billing cycle, it seems that their docs got a bit better. If the billing cycle starts at 31st of January they're supposed to bill on Feb 1st, take a look: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscription_billing_cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also a bit confused, but found a good reference on their docs:

> Recurring payments are collected on the same day of the month. If the
>   initial recurring payment falls on the 31st, PayPal eventually adjusts
>   the billing cycle to the 1st of the month. If the initial recurring
>   payment falls on the 29th or 30th, PayPal adjusts the billing cycle to
>   the 1st of the month on the following February.

Following what they've specified, I think the right answer to to both of your questions is:

**It would be adjusted to March 1st**.

For more examples, this reference might help:

- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscription_billing_cycles/

Comment: The documentation now says PayPal "adjusts the billing cycle to the **last** of the month", although the examples still show the cycle being adjusted to the 1st of the month. https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscription-billing-cycles/